# SMB 2 or 3 with SAMBA version 4.3.11

Tags: networking, samba, smb

With the new windows update killing support for SMB 1, I'm attempting to force my ubuntu (desktop version) server to use SMB 2 or 3. I've been around and it says to change the min protocol and max protocol settings in the smb.conf, but those options don't seem to exist. any ideas? I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

The exact settings are:

- client min protocol
- client max protocol

Then you should configure your **/etc/samba/smb.conf** with the following commands on **[GLOBAL]** section

```
[GLOBAL]
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
```

after that you should restart smb service as root:

```
# systemctl restart smb
# systemctl restart nmd
```

**man smb.conf** for more details

Comment: how do I access the [GLOBAL] section from the command line?

Comment: --option=<name>=<value>  **man smbd** for details. Anyway to configure smb.conf you must edit the file with __vim__ or __nano__  The [GLOBAL] sectin is at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The issue I'm having is even open in vim, the client min/max protocol settings simply aren't there. At the top of the page, it says "Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which are not shown in this example."

Comment: the lines that begin with # are comments. If the "client min protocol" is not there you have to add it. As I said you have to open /etc/samba/smb.conf with vim and go under [GLOBAL] section and there add the client min/max protocol configuration.  Then restart the service.

Comment: Okay, I've added the commands. with smbstatus, it shows my username and says SMB3_02 under protocol version. I am still unable to access the server from my windows PC. I'm assuming at this point, it's no longer an Ubuntu issue, correct?

Comment: how do u try to connect to the samba server from windows ?

Comment: I just type the ip address into windows explorer. It shows me the server and all of the shared drives but says I don't have permissions to access the drives. When I looked around for an answer originally, people were saying this is an issue with the SMB1 being phased out. I can still access the share from my other pc that has not been updated yet.

Comment: oh shoot, I'm sorry. Looking over the smbstatus again, it shows all of my working machines as SMB3_02, but the IP address from the problem pc shows Nobody under username, nogroup under group, and unknown under protocol version

Comment: you should try to look in the samba logs under /var/log/samba/ directory  if the logs have not enough details  try to add the **log level = 3** line in the **/etc/samba/smb.conf** under the **[GLOBAL]**  section. Then restart the service, try to connect to the samba server and go the logs directory to look the errors.

Comment: [2018/02/26 14:05:15.744895,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3259(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/ministereth failed. Permission denied

Comment: Just a suggestion. Run the following command so that you can see how your usershare is set up: "net usershare info --long" Then look at the permissions of the folder being shared to see if it is the same as your share settings. Does "nobody" have Linux permissions to access the folder being shared?

Comment: [Helms Deep]
path=/media/daniel/Helms Deep
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

It's giving me this for each of my shares, which looks to me like everyone has permissions and guests are ok. Am I correct in this assumption? By Linux Permissions, do you mean permissions from the Linux server or something client side? Anyone attached to my network has permissions accordiing to Linux.

Comment: Nope. Linux permissions would be the permissions on /media/daniel/Helms Deep - as in: "ls -dl "/media/daniel/Helms Deep". But that is only one problem you have. A guest user will never get to the "Helms Deep" folder because of the access contro list on the /media/daniel folder. This would never have worked and again has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: My recommendation since all of your shares allow guest access is to edit smb.conf again and add a line right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line that looks like this: force user = daniel Then restart smbd again.

Comment: $ systemctl ... isn't working on Xenial 16.04. Only $ service smbd restart and $ service nmbd restart (Not nmd) for the NetBIOS name server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mounting your shares through `fstab` on the client, then include `vers=3.0` as an option after `cifs` and that will set up a SMB 3.0 connection.

When I tried to up the min protocols on the server, many of my clients could not connect.  I had better luck setting the version number on the client side. (I am still learning this myself.)

Answer (score 0):

2 different min/max protocols.

When a client machine to your Ubuntu server accesses your machine it will negotiate which smb dialect to use between two settings on the server: **server min protocol** and **server max protocol**. By default those settings are **lanman1** and **SMB3**. If your client machine does not want to access your machine using smb1 it can go all the way up to SMB3 without changing anything on the server.

client min / max protocol is for Ubuntu connecting to another server and changing it did nothing relative to this question.

Something else appears to be a problem with your one client.